# ng-repeat com dados do banco mysql

Tags: php, angularjs

tenho 02 tabelas no banco (prospect e oportunidade) as duas tabelas tem o prospectId. Como eu faço para exibir no ng-repeat. Estava tentando inner join na consulta php e retorna esse erro no angular "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]". Alguem tem algum exemplo.

```
/* Lista oportunidade */ 
$scope.listaOportunidades = []; 
var carregaOportunidades = function () { 
 $http.get("models/readOportunidades.php")
     .then(function (response) { 
            $scope.listaOportunidades = response.data; 
      }); 
 }; 
carregaOportunidades();
```

---

```
<?php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\controllers\DB\Conn;

$PDO = new Conn;

$query = $PDO->getConn()->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_prospect INNER JOIN tb_oportunidade ON tb_prospect.prospectId=oportunidadeCliente');
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $return[]= $row;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

É necessários mais informações para entender o que está acontecendo no seu código:

- Código HTML onde você está usando a diretiva;
- Lista retornada pela sua Query;

Pelo erro, existem itens duplicados (no entendimento do angular) durante o ng-repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Dessa forma, acredito que usando o exemplo abaixo irá funcionar:

```
<div ng-repeat="valor in listaOportunidades track by valor.VALOR_UNICO_DO_REGISTRO"></div>
```

Sugiro também que reveja a query.

Comment: Essa parte já consegui resolver agora retorna os dados certinho, estou conseguindo pegar os dados das tabelas com inner join. Valeu!